# How to use the current MVC formatter config for manual serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I'm attempting to write some middleware that wraps all responses from WebApi calls. Using the method below, I can wrap the object and serialize it as JSON, which is fine for my current needs, but this forces all responses as JSON (and uses its own default formatters).
Ideally, I'd like to use the currently configured MVC Formatters to perform this, so if the consumer is using an XML formatter, then this middleware would do the same.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var currentBody = context.Response.Body;
    var requestData = RequestData.Create();

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        context.Response.Body = memoryStream;
        await _next(context);

        // reset the body
        context.Response.Body = currentBody;
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var jsonResult = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();

        requestData.Size = jsonResult.Length;
        requestData.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)context.Response.StatusCode;
        requestData.GetResult(jsonResult);
        requestData.Complete();

        var wrappedResponse = _options.CreateResponse(requestData);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrappedResponse));
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to access that serializer? I'd like to pass it through to this middleware ideally.

To be clear - This middleware should remain agnostic of whatever the return objects are from WebApi. I do not want the endpoints to be concerned with this wrapper.

The intention of this middleware is to intercept and wrap EVERY result with metadata regardless of HTTP status. The wrapper is not related to the actual response (other than determining the size).

My question relates to keeping the serializer format consistent across the middleware i.e. I need to re-use whatever the MVC Formatter has been configured.

Comment: Why write *any* of this code instead of simply returning an object from an action with eg `Ok(result)`? Web API itself will format it into JSON. If you want to use different formatters, *configure* Web API to do so and don't make any other changes.

Comment: What is this code trying to do anyway? Why does it include its own serialization? Perhaps the real question is how to register this class so it runs before the formatters?

Comment: The [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article in the docs shows how to use configure formatters and even force the use of specific formatters per action.

Comment: The [Ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#ordering) section in the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) document explains that the order the  components are added in the Configuration method affects their execution order. Perhaps this middleware should be added *after* the formatters, ie the call to `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`?

Comment: You have questioned why I am doing something, then marked it as a duplicate of a question that is not related. I don't think you should be doing that.

Comment: Please see my edits for my reasons and intentions for this class. To my knowledge, this is a perfectly acceptable question of accessing the currently configured MvcFormatters from inside of custom middleware.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is. The duplicate *Is* a duplicate - how to use XML? Use the XML formatter. `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` is how you do that. Other middleware shouldn't do the work of formatters. RIght now it' hard to understand what's going on. Clearly, you shouldn't be formatting but what is that code doing? Did you *try* removing the formatting code and just wrapping the data?

Comment: Where did I ask the question "How to use XML?"

Comment: First paragraph `but this forces all responses as JSON (and uses its own default formatters). Ideally, I'd like to use the currently configured MVC Formatters to perform this, so if the consumer is using an XML formatter, then this middleware would do the same.`. The answer is `don't do any of it, leave it to the proper middleware`. Which brings as to `what is the question ?`

Comment: If you *remove* the formatting code, just wrap the response, what do you get? Don't the formatters get the wrapped response? If so why? Is your middleware positiong after the formatters perhaps? How was it added, in what order?

Comment: Okay perhaps I'll ask in a different way... 
I need to measure the length of the response object (string) BEFORE the wrapper is applied, in WHATEVER the format is. I then want to use the same formatter to serialize the wrapped object.
Json will naturally be smaller/shorter than XML.
How can I do this with middleware?

Comment: The natural response is already serialized - in this case it's Json, but this middleware doesn't know that, but measures it anyway, and serializes the whole thing as Json. I don't want that.

Comment: No, the middleware will use the formatter requested by the *client* as long as it's configured. `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` will configure the XML formatter. The payload *won't* be a string in the general case, it will be an object like a DTO or a simple value like an `int`. ONLY IF you explicitly return a JSON string with `Json(someData)` can you assume this will be a Json string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174897/discussion-between-mortware-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Btw `Json` doesn't really return a Json string, it returns a JsonResult object that *will* serialize the data or data stream as Json. You could even create eg an ExcelResult object that returns an `xlsx` file. Perhaps what you want should be done with a custom Result object?